# Connecting to SQL database works when ASP application is hosted in IIS Exress but doesn't work when hosted in Local IIS

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC API web service, I created a simple SQL connection object with a connection string in a Get method. I also created an Ado.net Data Model (with the same connection string) and wrote a LINQ statement to get a row from the database in the same Get method.

When the MVC application is set to IIS Express, both the ado.net connection.open() command and the Entity Framework LINQ statement work and data is retrieved from the database.

However, when I change to Local IIS (I need it to be Local IIS), connecting to the database fails using both ways and this is the error that appears in either way:

[image: error image]

Comment: the error is writen in your error message. Apply to your DBA for help with permissions.

Comment: Can you post your connection string?  Make sure to scrub any passwords out of it.

Comment: In case of ADO.net:  SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=MyOwnTaxDatabase;Integrated Security = SSPI");

Comment: In case of calling from Entity Framework, the automatically created connection string created in the web.config is as follows:     <add name="MyOwnTaxDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;initial catalog=MyOwnTaxDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: both are working if I choose IIS Express. The ado.net commands following the declaration of the SQL connection object and a LINQ command depending on Entity Framework

Answer (score 0):

When you're running with Local IIS using Integrated Security in your SQL Server connection, the connection to your SQL Server instance is being made under the context of the account the IIS App Pool is running as.  You need to do one of the following:

- Change what account your IIS App Pool is using
- Grant access in the db to the account the IIS App Pool
- Switch to a SQL Login

This was not the case when using IIS Express because IIS Express runs under the context of YOUR account, which I'm assuming does have permissions to the database.

Comment: Does the article in this link describe how to do your first option or this is a different thing ?

Comment: https://support.appliedi.net/kb/how-to-manually-create-a-site-application-pool-identity-in-iis7/

Comment: @AhmedWaguih Yes, that's it